Time frame effect package run in ssis?
I just inherited a ssis package. one of the variable is calling itself.. so the DALIC is always failing. It scheduled daily in the morning around 7 am est . I fixed it now.
The problem is before I notice that, I deployed to the server in the afternoon. and test ran it.. It succussed!! Then I didn't do anything, but next morning it failed again?
Why is that?
Please advise me why the time frame can effect package failure thing?enter image description here
Tried: This package just send table to flat file. It does nothing else.. the date is set by a stored procedure, which basically just tell today's date.

Sounds like you need to implement some logging or error handling so you can get more info about why it's failing.

I have logging and I knew why it's failing. I just don't know why it was succussed while it should fail... The only difference of the two jobs is the succeed one ran in the afternoon and I ran it for testing.. The failing ones are in the morning and followed by server schedule...

It's really hard to help when you haven't shared the error message you're getting. In my experience, when a package works and then fails later, there is something that changed even though I initially think there isn't any change. Usually something in the data, but it could be something on the Server as well.
